Gradle Build Fails with 'Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file' Error in React Native Android Project
What went wrong:
Error resolving plugin [id: 'com.facebook.react', version: '0.75.3', apply: false]

A problem occurred configuring project ':gradle-plugin'.
Could not create service of type OutputFilesRepository using ExecutionGradleServices.createOutputFilesRepository().
> Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.

I was trying to build and run my React Native Android project using npx react-native run-android. I expected the app to compile and install successfully on my Android device/emulator. However, the build failed with the error: 'Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0.' I tried deleting the .gradle folder, cleaning the build cache, and checking my Gradle version, but the issue persists. I was tyring with all these below  versions but still i am getting issue , this is the react-native vesrion i am using   "react-native": "^0.75.3" Any insights on resolving this would be appreciated.
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.8-all.zip
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
# distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip


This question is similar to: Error:Unexpected lock protocol found in lock file. Expected 3, found 0. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
